# Upgrading CentOS from 7 to 8

Tags: centos, package-management, upgrade

I'm getting the below error while installing kernel-core  after this command:

```
dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync
```

Errors:

```
# dnf -y install kernel-core
Last metadata expiration check: 0:23:59 ago on Sat 25 Jul 2020 11:58:57 PM IST.
Error:
 Problem: package kexec-tools-2.0.20-14.el8.x86_64 requires dracut >= 049-24, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package dracut-049-70.git20200228.el8.x86_64 requires systemd-udev >= 219, but none of the providers can be installed
  - problem with installed package kexec-tools-2.0.15-43.el7.x86_64
  - package systemd-udev-239-30.el8_2.x86_64 obsoletes systemd < 229-5 provided by systemd-219-73.el7_8.8.x86_64
  - package kernel-core-4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 conflicts with kexec-tools < 2.0.20-8 provided by kexec-tools-2.0.15-43.el7.x86_64
  - package systemd-sysv-219-73.el7_8.8.x86_64 requires systemd = 219-73.el7_8.8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package systemd-sysv-219-73.el7_8.8.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no official support from upgrading from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8. If you follow instructions from random people on the internet, you’ll most likely end up with a broken system.  The official recommendation is to install a new CentOS 8 system and migrate your data.

If you do end up getting something running and end up having problems, people who support CentOS will tell you to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
dnf remove python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_7.noarch 
dnf -y install kernel-core --best --allowerasing
```

Ran into same thing but removed what I could for el7_7.noarch and the last 2 above commands did it for me.